# Amazon EC2 AMI linux2 amazon-linux-extras basearch error

Tags: linux, webserver, amazon-ec2

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/__main__.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli_main([arg for arg in argv[1:] if arg != "-v"]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/cli.py", line 419, in main
    action(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/cli.py", line 245, in cmd_install
    catalog = get_catalog(insist_stable_ordinal=any(re.match(r"^[0-9]+$", arg) for arg in args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/software_catalog.py", line 120, in get_catalog
    catalog = fetch_new_catalog()  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/software_catalog.py", line 92, in fetch_new_catalog
    url = CATALOG_URL.format(**yumvars)
KeyError: u'basearch'
```

Getting this error saying Basesearch key error. Have to install nginx

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Sijo James John](https://superuser.com/a/1450597/498601) highlights the problem of `basearch` having `None` as a default value, but there's an alternative to modifying the `software_catalog.py` file. The code in that file checks for environmental variable overrides for each key that match the key name in all caps. In this case, setting `BASEARCH` will override. In my case, `basearch` needs to be `x86_64`.

I'm also using python 3 by default, but `amazon-linux-extras` requires python 2.7 due to using `yum`. Fortunately, `amazon-linux-extras` also looks for a `PYTHON` environment variable override before using the default `python` command.

So here's a sample command that runs successfully on my machine:

```
PYTHON=python2 BASEARCH=x86_64 amazon-linux-extras list
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured out the problem

First find the base arch with this code

```
python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'

{'arch': 'ia32e',
```

'awsdomain': 'amazonaws.com',
 'awsregion': 'eu-*****',
 'basearch': 'x86_64',
 'product': 'core',
 'releasever': '2',
 'target': 'latest',
 'uuid': '**************'}

Then edit

```
nano /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras/software_catalog.py
```

to change the line

```
for name, default in (("awsdomain", "amazonaws.com"), ("awsregion", "default"), ("releasever", "2"), ("basearch", None)):
```

to

```
for name, default in (("awsdomain", "amazonaws.com"), ("awsregion", "default"), ("releasever", "2"), ("basearch", "x86_64")):
```

The problem is that the *basearch* default is set as None which causes the dict to not have a key value pair for *basearch*.